# Pass object to html String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am in a situation here, i think its a simple one but i can't sort it out.
I Have a HTML element where i should pass a json Object

code

```
var x = "<li id='tag_1'></li>"
var obj = {"name":"krishna","id":"krish1"}
```

when I convert this to html i want to get Like this

```
<li id="tag_1" data-options={obj}></li>
```

I tried  `$(x).data("options",{obj}),`
tried to pass as a string when creating the html element,but did'nt work

Thanks

Comment: JSON is a string, not an object, and also `.data` will not create `data-options` for you. Take a look at the jQuery spec of what [it actually does](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: `{obj}` is invalid syntax. You can simply use `$(x).data('options', obj)`. It will, however, not be saved on the HTML tag but rather just in jQuery's memory. Example: `$('body').data('foo', { foo: 'bar' }); $('body').data('foo');` gives `Object {foo: "bar"}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(x).data("options",{obj})` is a perfectly good way to do it, provided you fix the syntax error. Just pass `obj` directly, and jQuery will save it as an object. It will not, however, be added as an attribute.

```
$(x).data("options",obj)
```

If you look at the [documentation for `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) it specifies that your value doesn't have to be a string:

> **value**
>   Type: [Anything](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Anything)
>   The new data value; **this can be any Javascript type except `undefined`**.

Comment: i did this fiddel but not woking,i tried to get the options to html but not working

Comment: "It will not, however, be added as an attribute." It's just saved in memory to be accessed by `$(x).data('options')`. Also, you're recreating the jQuery object when you append it. You need to save the same object.

Comment: @Krishna [**It works fine**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lt51nmkm/1/). Your problem was that when you do `$('<tag>')` you create a *new* element. You need to save the reference to this element and then use that (as you can see using my fiddle).

Comment: So what change should i do in that fiddle... or what change in code should i do, to access that obj

Comment: @Krishna Did you see my [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lt51nmkm/1/)? Your answer is already there? Instead of `$(x).foo(); $(x).abc();` then use `var xx = $(x); xx.foo(); xx.abc();`

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(x).attr("data-options",JSON.stringify(obj))`

If you don't want it printed in your HTML use `$(x).data("options",obj)`

Comment: fiddle.jshell.net/Lt51nmkm